# "Truth" as a reply instead of "True"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, slang, conversation

I think this sentence is grammatically correct:

> - You need a new pair of glasses.
> - True.

However, I've heard sometimes someone says *Truth* instead of *True*:

> - You need a new pair of glasses.
> - **Truth**.

Is this correct? Or is it a well-known slang term? Or is it just plain wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just unusual. Sometimes that's a good thing, sometimes not.

Comment: Or in UK or OZ vernacular, [**Strewth!**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strewth) but its usage is different.

Comment: @WeatherVane isn't 'strewth' used instead of 'for real'?

Comment: @Bizhan I always thought it was from "That's the truth" or "God's truth" and corrupted into an exclamation.

Comment: @WeatherVane I feel it has more of a "you speak the truth" vibe.

Comment: Well-known slang/colloquialism, at least in California American English. *[You speak the] truth.*

Answer (score 3):

Truth and true are subtly different in that [true](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/true), in this sense, is more about accuracy and facts.  [Truth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truth) extends into a person's veracity, belief system, and perception of reality.  Truth tends to be more a collective term - "Your truth and mine differ" is a reasonable statement.  I agree that "Truth" would be a less likely answer to the cited statement, but it might be an answer to someone saying "God created the Universe".  "(That's) True" as an answer would discount a knowledge that that might not be universally accepted, while "(You speak the) Truth" would indicate that it matches the speakers view of reality.

Answer (score 1):

"True" is short for "that's true", and is definitely more widespread than "truth". "Truth" will definitely sound like slang to others.

Comment: But some people say, "That's the truth," and "truth" alone is short for that. It's not slang, it's just a different phrasing.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee Shortenings may (1) not be considered acceptable at all, sincorrect (b) be considered a slang usage, innit (c) be considered totally acceptable (bus, phone ...). Your explanation is probably correct, but, together with your acceptability rating, like the answerer's claim that 'Truth!' is slang, needs supporting evidence.